Blood Pressure and Compliance
Need some insight into the relationship between blood pressure and arterial compliance(Change in Volume/Change in Pressure). Most text books suggest that systolic blood pressure has an inverse relationship with compliance.
I understand that systolic blood pressure is dependent on cardiac output, resistance and arterial stiffness(measured by compliance).
However, I still cannot understand the exact biophysical reason. It doesnt make intuitive sense right now

I wonder if you might add an explanation of what you mean by compliance here. Remember to also show your prior research when editing.

It's a part of the way we do things here, we encourage self-learning and people to show what research they've done when asking and where they got stuck. See the [ask] section of the [help] for clarification. Could you edit the question rather than leaving comments as they can't be guaranteed to stick around. Remember we also have a [medicalsciences.se] site.

Sure, thank you!!

I think it's pretty intuitive if you start with  the right understanding of the individual concepts.
First, the homeostatic goal of the cardiovascular system is to deliver a given flow rate for a given need. Flow (volume/time) is what delivers enough oxygen to tissues.
Second, compliance is best understood as the stretchiness of the system. A balloon has really high compliance: a little pressure in the system increases the volume. A sealed glass jar has very little compliance: it's going to stay the same volume even as pressures get high.
Third, the heart necessarily delivers all of the flow for a cycle in a relatively short time. It's not providing a constant flow, it's providing a pulsatile flow.
Where does all that blood go with each beat? It doesn't flow through the whole system during systole, it fills the proximal arteries, and they stretch to contain the volume, which then flows through the system for the rest of the cycle. If they're very stretchy, they will fill up without taking much pressure. If they're rigid and less stretchy, it takes more pressure for that same volume to be able to get into those same vessels.
Think of "systolic blood pressure" as "how much pressure the heart needs to push a sufficient volume of blood into the arteries". If the arteries are compliant, it doesn't take much pressure. If they are stiff (e.g. atherosclerosis) it takes more pressure.

So from what I understand. If the proximal artery is easily distensible, then it will need less pressure to stretch and hence systolic pressure will be low, right?

@user141356 Yes, that's right.

Thank you, I kinda get it now!!
